# React useState hook, calling setState with function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-hooks, state

There is a concept in React (when using hooks) that confuses me.

I made a component for explanation (that increases a counter):

```js
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0); // counter hook

// code will follow

// render
return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={handleClick}>+</button>
    <h3>{counter}</h3>
  </div>
);
```

For the handler function, I have seen different options to set the state.

First method (using `setState()` normally):

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  setCounter(counter + 1);
};
```

Second method (creating a function inside `setState()` and returning the new value):

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  setCounter((counter) => {
    return counter + 1;
  });
};
```

I thought the difference would be that with the second method, you could immediately do a callback after setting the state, like this:

```js
const handleClick = () => {
  setCounter((counter) => {
      return counter + 1;
    }, () => {
      console.log(counter); // trying callback after state is set
  });
};
```

But when trying this (with both methods), the console displays the following error message:

> *Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().*

So I think in both cases, using `useEffect()` as a callback on `setState()` is the right way.

My question is: what is the difference between the two methods and what method is best to set the state. I have read about state immutability but can not immediately see how it would make a difference in this example.

Comment: Voting to reopen because the linked question is about the Component this.setState, and this question is about the functional useState's second return argument. They're entirely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it's the same. 
 
Basically when your state is computed with your previous state you can use the second approach which gets the previous value.

Have a look in React docs about this:

[Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Comment: This does not answer the question.  You do not have access to the newly set state even when passing a function to `useState`, only the previous one.

Comment: I didn't say that there is an access the newly state at all when passing a callback,
just saying that the second approach is useful when there is a need to update the new state based on the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is gaining some attention I will add this example.

```
<button onClick={() => setCount(0)}>Reset</button>
<button onClick={() => setCount((prevCount) => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
<button onClick={() => setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
```

You can see that for `+` and `-` the functional `setState`is being used, this is because the new state value is computed using the previous state (you are adding/subtracting from the previous count value).

The `reset` button is using the normal form, because it doesn't compute the new state value based on a computation on the old value, it always just sets it to a fixed number (for example `0`).

So in my case, the best thing to do would have been using the functional `setState`.